# Timeout Feature Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, timeout, mute

How do I add the **timeout** function in `discord.js` ?

Please note I'm talking about the new **timeout** feature, not like assigning a `mutedrole`

Answer (score 7):

According to discord.js's documentation, you need to use [`GuildMember#timeout`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/GuildMember:Class#timeout), so your code should look something like this:

```js
guildMember.timeout(5 * 60 * 1000)
.then(() => console.log("Member has been timed out"))
.catch(console.log);
```